# Idiomatic way to set property to function value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

To hopefully head off the "primarily-opinion-based" close-button-clickers, I'm not looking for opinions on the "best" way to do this; I'm just wondering if there is a more straightforward solution that I'm missing.

My goal is to add the same `onclick` method to all of the (hundreds of) checkboxes on my page.  My first attempt at a jQuery solution was this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('onclick', function(){alert("Boop!");})
```

But that runs into the computed-value behavior of $.prop() and calls the function immediately for each checkbox.

So I can do this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('onclick', function(){return function() {alert("Boop!");}})
```

But that feels awfully workaround-y.  Alternatively, I could do this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(_, cb) {
  cb.onclick = function(){alert("Boop!");};  
});
```

But that seems uncharacteristically manual for jQuery.

So am I missing a more straightforward solution?

Comment: One option if you really wanted to assign a function to `onclick`  would be `.prop('onclick', function f(){alert("Boop!"); return f})`

Comment: @squint - that would still call the function on page load (in this case, resulting in hundreds of "Boop!" alert boxes).

Comment: Brain freeze. You're right of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the function and then simply refer to it by name:

```
function handler() { alert("Boop!"); }

$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", handler);
```

Note that you shouldn't be setting up event handlers by setting the "onfoo" properties.

*edit* — if what you want to avoid is adding the handler over and over again, use delegation:

```
$("body").on("click", "input:checkbox", handler);
```

That creates only one event handler registration. As "click" events bubble up the DOM to the body, jQuery will check to see which ones targeted elements that match the selector, and invoke your handler for those that do. (*Opinion* — I've mostly adopted the practice of *exclusively* using body-level delegation for all events. It makes things a lot less messy.)

Comment: Thanks, @Pointy - that answers my question (the use of `on` to set an event handler, instead of using `prop` to manually set the `onevent` property, side-steps the computed-value behavior of `prop`).  Declaring the function and giving it a name is good practice, but not relevant to my question.

Comment: Also, the body-level delegation idea is a lot cleaner!

Comment: @MarkReed yes, you get rid of a lot of the mess from things like dynamic modal dialogs - the handlers are *always* there, so there's no need for code to do setup work on every piece of dynamic content. Also, it's *way* more efficient: the per-event tests to see if an event target matches some selectors are quite fast and don't impact site responsiveness at all.

Answer (score 1):

you have to write event no use `prop`:

```
$('input:checkbox').on('click', function(){alert("Boop!");})
```

i will suggest to use **change** event for checkbox not **click**:

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function(){
   if(this.checked)
   {
   alert("checked");
   }

});
```

Comment: The "change" event was problematic in older versions of Internet Explorer because it wouldn't fire until the control lost focus.

Comment: @Pointy: Doesn't jQuery remedy that?

Comment: Thanks, @Ehsan.  Accepted Pointy's answer simply because he got there first.

Comment: @squint I don't recall that it did, but it's been a while since I worried about it. That seems like a problematic thing for the library to deal with; it'd have to have code to synthesize a "change" event when it *should* happen, and "eat" the browser-generated "change" event when that one happens.